# Datagrid Items.Add not displaying content - WPF/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid called dgFiles that has 4 columns and populates each column with a string. When I go to add a Item to my datagrid using

```
//Add Row
MessageBox.Show(fileName + " " + dateModified + " " + fileType + " " + fileLength);
dgFiles.Items.Add(new object[] { fileName, dateModified, fileType, fileLength + " kb" });
dgFiles.Items.Refresh();
```

the messagebox displays the correct strings I want to populate my datagrid with, however my datagrid simply displays a blank row.

[image: dgFiles]

The code to my XAML Datagrid

```
    <!--Data Grid-->
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgFiles" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" RowHeaderWidth="0" MouseDoubleClick="dgFiles_MouseDoubleClick">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="File Name"      Width="30*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Modified"  Width="40*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type"           Width="14*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size"           Width="10*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks, iato

Comment: Most people don't manually use the Items collection like that. The most wonderful thing about WPF is its binding functionality. The typical approach would be to create a class with FileName, DateModified, Type, and Size properties to hold the data, add instances of this class to an ObservableCollection. Then in the XAML you can state <DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding NameOfObservableCollection} ...

Comment: @ashbygeek thank you I will give this a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `Binding` property of each column to a binding that binds to a *public property* of the data item that you add to the `Items`/`ItemsSource` collection:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="File Name" Binding="{Binding Filename}" Width="30*"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Modified" Binding="{Binding Date}" Width="40*"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type}" Width="14*"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Size}" Width="10*"/>
```

This also means that your data object must expose *public properties*:

```
dgFiles.Items.Add(new { FileName = fileName, Date = dateModified, Type = fileType, Size = fileLength + " kb" });
```

If you want to be able to edit the data in the `DataGrid` you cannot add anonymous objects to its `Items` property though. Instead you should define a class with your properties and set the `ItemsSource` to an `IEnumerable` of this type:

```
List<YourClass> items = new List<YourClass>();
items.Add(new YourClass { FileName = fileName, Date = dateModified, Type = fileType, Size = fileLength + " kb" });
dgFiles.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: Im still realtively new to XAML so this made alot of sense to me :) Thank you !